# How can I place prefabs into a world in Unity?

Tags: unity, roguelikes

I've looked around for a bit and can't seem to find any way to get a prefab with "Resource.Load" and then to place that object into the world. I'm making a roguelike so when the player enters a room, all rooms around load in. The room to the top would load a random prefab from a list of rooms, check if there's already a room where it wants to go and then `PlacePrefab(transform.position, transform.position + 10units);` So it would place the prefab 10 units above where the current room is (All code for the rooms will run from a centre object and the prefab would be placed on the centre.)

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: You're aware of [the Instantiate method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)?

Comment: @DMGregory, Oh wow. Thanks. I hadn't seen that in anything but `Instanciate(object);` where it just made the object on the object that turned it on. If you want to make it an answer then I can give you the tick :) Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend that you share your prefab-spawning script as an answer. That will probably be more useful to future users than just a link to the docs. ;)

Comment: Alright, I'm working on that now. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @DMGregory, Hey. I've been working on the code and finally got to the point of testing it. I've got `GameObject newPrefab = Resources.Load("Test Level", typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject;
        Instantiate(newPrefab, new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 12, transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);`
but there's an error. "The object is null". I believe this is because it loads the folder "Test Level" not the prefab by the name. Is there any way to make it load just the file? Thanks :)

Comment: @DMGregory I was just wondering if you knew a way around this? The question would be named the same and this one is still on the original page :)

Comment: Nevermind, got it working :) Thanks for all the help. (Couldn't edit last because 5 minute rule)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @DMGregory for helping :)

My code for doing this is:

```
newPrefab = Resources.Load("SizeTest", typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject;
Instantiate(newPrefab, new Vector3(transform.position.x - 8, transform.position.y - 5, transform.position.z), Quaternion.identity);
```

This loads a 16x10 prefab room above the current room. Change the numbers for where you want it to load. It loads off a middle or centre point where the code is attached to.

Something I didn't realise is that you need to make your files in a "Resources" folder. I thought "Resources" was the same as "Assets". Put everything in there and then the string in the `Resources.Load` is the file name (No extension)

Hopefully this can help someone doing something similar out :)